# What does cpu_idle() do in the kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm reading [start_kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.1.6/source/init/main.c#L467) function in `/init/main.c`. 
The last function called in `start_kernel` is `rest_init` and at the end of `rest_init`, `cpu_idle` is called. 
My question is why it's called as the last function of `start_kernel` routine and what does it do?

Comment: you mean more than it is described? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.1.6/source/arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c#L109

Comment: Cpu_idle puts cpu on low power mode, while there is no threads ready to run. It is the last, because it should be launched after all usefull work at start is done